# How to get 'text' from a file, dynamically updated?

Tags: vb.net

I try to test something like: Turning a 'file' as 'database'. Which mainly have a 'Sender' and a 'Receiver' program. 
For 'Sender', System Time (or Random value) (in one line only like: 1513424678122) is written into file 'x.txt', while 'Receiver' is going to read the text from it. 
The problem occur in 'receiving'. 
In 'Receiver', the code is something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Click to start receive
    i.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub i_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles i.Tick
    'Read text
    Dim f As String
    f = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("\\192.168.42.129@8081\storage\sdcard0\X.txt")
    Lb1.Items.Add(f)
End Sub
```

Also tested with:

```
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("\\192.168.42.129@8081\storage\sdcard0\X.txt")
    Dim line As String
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    Lb1.Items.Add(line)
```

But, the result shown: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9H6P.png), which all the 'text' is the same.

> Example: 
>   Sender: 111, 222, 333, 444
>   Receiver: 111, 111, 111, 111

So, I wonder is there any way to 'update' the data?

Thank you.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU5Bq.png)

Comment: are your data saved as lines in the text?

Comment: It is 1 line only, like: 1513424678122

Comment: I don't understand your question: It looks like your receiver is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Does your sender really changes anything? It seems like it doesn't. Or do you want the Receiver to only show new changes and not the same line over and over?

Comment: @Heinzi The 'Receiver' suppose to receive the 'System time' send by 'Sender'

Comment: The 'Receiver' suppose to update the 'text' from the file and add item into ListBox1 (Something like 'History')

Comment: The exact text file (X.txt), the text exactly changes (Open manually using Notepad to look). Seems like the System.IO does not refresh...

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand your problem now. Your .NET code (`ReadAllText`) looks fine, so we need to do some debugging: Does the problem also occur if you use a local file instead of a network share?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU5Bq.png

Comment: Just now tested with Local, but still the same. Looks like the 'Receiver' stacks at older 'history'...